# Performance optimization on specific mysql query?

Tags: mysql

how can I optimize in terms of performance the following query while keep the same result?

```
SELECT
    a.country,
    count(DISTINCT b.`hash`)
FROM
    audience a,
    behaviour b
WHERE
    DATE(b.`timestamp`) = '2016-03-31'
    AND b.`hash` = a.`hash`
GROUP BY
    a.country;
```

Comment: add indexes on both `hash` columns and avoid usage of DATE() in WHERE clause - use `b.timestamp BETWEEN '2016-03-31 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-31 23:59:59'` instead. `explain` output will be helpful as well.

Comment: You've given no details regarding your schema, indexes, no sample data, and no execution plan output. How do you seriously expect us to help you?

Comment: @Rahautos Actually the `,` operator here _is_ a variant of a `JOIN`.

Comment: add indexes on both where clause columns. You can also create procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add indexes on all columns used in `WHERE` clause and use `BETWEEN...AND` for the timestamp instead of `DATE()` function:

```
ALTER TABLE `behaviour` 
ADD INDEX `ts_IDX` (`timestamp`),
ADD INDEX `hash_IDX` (`hash`);
---------------------------------
ALTER TABLE `audience` 
ADD INDEX `hash_IDX` (`hash`);
---------------------------------
SELECT
    a.country,
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.`hash`)
FROM
    audience a
    INNER JOIN behaviour b ON b.`hash` = a.`hash`
WHERE
    b.`timestamp` BETWEEN '2016-03-31 00:00:00' AND '2016-03-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    a.country;
---------------------------------
```

This should help.